# Question about Jech's Set Theory

Tags: set-theory

On page 177 of the 3rd edition of Jech's *Set Theory* the sentence
(13.2) $\forall p_1\dots\forall p_n\forall X\exists Y\forall u(u\in Y\leftrightarrow u\in X\wedge\phi(u,p_1,\dots,p_n))$,
where $\phi$ is a $\Delta_0$ formula, is called an instance of $\Delta_0$-Separation. The text then says "a transitive class $M$ satisfies $\Delta_0$-Separation if for every $\Delta_0$ formula $\phi$, $M$ satisfies (13.2)". My question is this: what does it mean for $M$ to satisfy (13.2)? My thoughts: one of
(a) $M$ witnesses the $\exists Y$ quantifier,
(b) $(M,\in)$ is a model of (13.2).
But I'm lost. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: The second, I think. For every formula $\phi$ we have a different set (call it $Y_{\phi}$) witnessing the existential quantifier $\exists Y$.

Comment: Mauro, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It means the latter: $(M, \in)\models (13.2)$.

There's a convention here, which is often annoying at first, to conflate a transitive set $A$ with the structure $(A,\in)$ (or more accurately, $(A,\in\upharpoonright A^2$).

This will become clear later on when we invoke $(13.2)$ "within" such $M$.

Comment: "which is often${}^{[1]}$" [1]: citation needed.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I've seen that as a specific point of confusion repeatedly here; it's certainly helpful later on, but for many students starting out it can be weird.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Many thanks.